# ruby list child pids

Tags: ruby, process

How can I get pids of all child processes which were started from ruby script?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the current process with:

```
Process.pid
```

see http://whynotwiki.com/Ruby_/_Process_management for further details.

Then you could use operating specific commands to get the child pids. On unix based systems this would be something along the lines of

```
# Creating 3 child processes.
IO.popen('uname')
IO.popen('uname')
IO.popen('uname')

# Grabbing the pid.
pid = Process.pid

# Get the child pids.
pipe = IO.popen("ps -ef | grep #{pid}")

child_pids = pipe.readlines.map do |line|
  parts = line.lstrip.split(/\s+/)
  parts[1] if parts[2] == pid.to_s and parts[1] != pipe.pid.to_s
end.compact

# Show the child processes.
puts child_pids
```

Tested on osx+ubuntu.

I admit that this probably doesn't work on all unix systems as I believe the output of `ps -ef` varies slightly on different unix flavors.

Comment: `Process.pid` returns the pid of the current process, not the parent process. To get the parent process pid, do `Process.ppid`.

Comment: Just an error in the comments we need the current process, as this will be the parent of the child processes.

Comment: Just a few cents: "ps o pid= --ppid #{pid}" might be handier than "ps -ef | grep #{pid}" and you won't have to filter out unneeded lines and fields in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Process.fork responds with the PID of the child spawned. Just keep track of them in an array as you spawn children. See http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Process.html#M003148.

Comment: It would be a good variant but in my case I have a method yielding a block and the only way to track all calls to fork, system, spawn, backtrick and others it to chain those methods through pid counter, but I hoped that there is easier way to get children pids

Answer (score 3):

Can be also done using `sys-proctable` gem:

```
require 'sys/proctable'

Sys::ProcTable.ps.select{ |pe| pe.ppid == $$ }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quiet complicated and is platform specific. You actually **cannot** find all sub-processes if they deliberately try to hide.

If you want to just kill spawned processes there are many options. For a test framework I chose two:
1. spawn processes with `pgid => true`
2. insert variable `MY_CUSTOM_COOKIE=asjdkahf`, then find procs with that cookie in environment and kill it.

FYI using `ps` to find out process hierarchy is very unreliable. If one process in the chain exits, then its sub-processes get a parent pid of `1` (on linux at least). So it's not worth implementing.